# Unable to select different account on google Sign In

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using firebase and google sign in. The problem is that when I click on the sign in button, it log in automatically even without any google account registered in firebase auth users! Also the "choose account" dialog doesn't appear when user isn't in firebase auth users and when it is. I would like to show this dialog.

LoginActivity

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.schooltest.MainActivity;
import com.example.schooltest.R;
import com.example.schooltest.ResetPasswordActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons.GoogleSignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private View mViewHelper;

    GoogleSignInButton button;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //check the current user
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email_address);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        final Button ahlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);
        TextView btnForgot = findViewById(R.id.forgot);
        TextView btnSignUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup_here_Button);
        button = (GoogleSignInButton) findViewById(R.id.login_google_btn);
        mViewHelper = findViewById(R.id.view_helper);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });


        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnForgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Checking the email id and password is Empty
        ahlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email is required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(password.length() < 6) {
                    inputPassword.setError("Password Must be >= 6 Characters");
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mViewHelper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ahlogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                //authenticate user
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mViewHelper.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                ahlogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();

                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "singInWithEmail:Fail");
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }

                        });
            }

        });


        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("430102477506-gsgi3mjgd1bie5ml5nf316no2ki3llvj.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {

                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Aut Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

SignUpActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.schooltest.MainActivity;
import com.example.schooltest.R;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons.GoogleSignInButton;


public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    EditText mName, mEmail,mPassword;
    Button mSignupBtn;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    View mViewHelper;

    GoogleSignInButton button;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.agree_terms)));

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.et_email_address);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        mSignupBtn = findViewById(R.id.create_btn);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);
        mViewHelper = findViewById(R.id.view_helper);
        button = findViewById(R.id.login_google_btn);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mSignupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String name = mName.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    mName.setError("Name is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(password.length() < 6) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password Must be >= 6 Characters");
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mViewHelper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSignupBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                // register the user in firebase

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Error !" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mViewHelper.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mSignupBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });

            }
        });


        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }

            }
        };

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("430102477506-gsgi3mjgd1bie5ml5nf316no2ki3llvj.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {

                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Aut Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

Main Activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.schooltest.login.LoginActivity;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String mName;
    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ClassFragment()).commit();


        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


        // Sets default values only once, first time this is called. The third
        // argument is a boolean that indicates whether the default values
        // should be set more than once. When false, the system sets the default
        // values only the first time it is called.
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_students, false);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_information, false);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_security, false);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_notifications, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null){
            sendToStart();
        }
    }

    private void sendToStart() {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullscreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();
    }

    /**
     * Inflates the menu, and adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     *
     * @param menu Menu to inflate.
     * @return Returns true if the menu inflated.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handles app bar item clicks.
     * Don't forget to add intent to addstudent
     * @param item Item clicked.
     * @return True if one of the defined items was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_addStudent:
                displayToast(getString(R.string.action_addStudent_message));
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this,
                        SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_logout_btn:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                sendToStart();
                return true;

            default:
                // Do nothing
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * Displays a Toast with the message.
     *
     * @param message Message to display
     */
    public void displayToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private  BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_class:
                            selectedFragment = new ClassFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_due:
                            selectedFragment = new DueFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_messages:
                            selectedFragment = new MessagesFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_class_updates:
                            selectedFragment = new ClassUpdatesFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };


}
```